# Automatic redirection to SF1 feed from Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios

Does anybody know how to prevent automatic redirection to feed (sf1) after mobile device goes to "sleep" mode (screen goes black). When you turn on screen again and click to any menu in navigation, you are automatically redirected to feed no matter what you click (even though you are on feed, when you click any other menu, you are directed to feed).

Does anybody has solution?

Thank you.